# How to install phpsh on windows 8

Tags: php, mysql, python-2.7, facebook-php-sdk, phpsh

Ive been download Python 2.7.6 recently.and olso ive been download phpsh(http://www.phpsh.org/)
.

My Question Is

1.Where i can place the phpsh files into the python

2.By following the instructions manual from there (https://github.com/facebook/phpsh).the python shows me an invalid syntax error.

3.How can i run phpsh in python command line.

I am newbie ..I done understand any of the python instruction manual..i just want to run php quickly to view the results.

Thanks,

Comment: You cannot run this `PHPSH` using `python` command line. phpsh is a simple php shell like python shell, where you can see what your inline code is doing. Moreover, python is only required to install the script.